# How do you do numpy.repeat in Eigen?

Tags: c++, numpy, eigen

Eigen has a `replicate` method similar to numpy.repeat, but it doesn't support repeating a variable number of times. For instance:

```
np.repeat(np.array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.], [ 3.,  4., 5.]]), [1, 2], axis=0)
```

gives

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.]])
```

How can I reproduce this behaviour in Eigen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
namespace Eigen {
    template <typename T>
    using ArrayXX = Array<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>;
}

template<typename A>
Eigen::ArrayXX<typename A::Scalar> repeat(const A& a, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXi>& repeats, const int axis) {
    typedef typename A::Scalar T;
    if (axis==0) {
        eigen_assert(a.rows() == repeats.size());
        const int new_rows = repeats.sum();
        Eigen::ArrayXX<T> repeated_array (new_rows, a.cols());
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats.size(); ++i) {
            const int k = repeats(i);
            repeated_array.middleRows(j, k) = a.row(i).colwise().replicate(k);
            j += k;
        }
        return repeated_array;
    } else {
        eigen_assert(a.cols() == repeats.size());
        const int new_cols = repeats.sum();
        Eigen::ArrayXX<T> repeated_array (a.rows(), new_cols);
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats.size(); ++i) {
            const int k = repeats(i);
            repeated_array.middleCols(j, k) = a.col(i).rowwise().replicate(k);
            j += k;
        }
        return repeated_array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the `eigen` library and try to encourage using the provided API as much as possible.  I honestly didn't look hard to find an internal function to provide what you ask so I'll believe you that one doesn't exist.  If I had to do this manually I would use the pointer access to the underlying array and `std::fill`.

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
Eigen::VectorXt<T> Repeat(const Eigen::VectorXt<T> &v, const Eigen::VectorXi &counts){
    Eigen::VectorXt<T> repeatedArray(counts.sum());
    T* dataPointer = repeatedArray.data();
    unsigned int placer = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < counts.size(); ++i){
        std::fill(dataPointer + placer, dataPointer + placer + counts(i), v(i));
        placer += counts(i);
    }
    return repeatedArray;
}
```

My `VectorXt` is similar to your `ArrayXX` just for a vector (`Matrix<T, Dynamic,1>`) because of the provided example.

Comment: Added a better example